# Can you call a modal window within a modal window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows, lightbox, modal-dialog

I have a modal window which is opened from a series of portlets. The window which is opened contains both text and images, and I'm trying to implement a lightbox script on the images. I have got the lightbox script to work in a separate file, and have copied that html into the .html value of the modal window, but when I click on any of the images it disregards the jQuery and takes me directly to a large version of the image.

Any one have any ideas?

Much appreciated,
Rich

P.S: 
Here is the project: http://djrb.co.uk/lightbox/tester.html

Comment: Try with following steps: 1. Move lightox jquery js file import to after jquery1.5.1 js 2. Already light box v2.05 is imported. so remove lightbox0.4 js which may conflict with diff version

Comment: Hi Karthi, thanks for your response. 
I have tried this, and it still doesn't work. Just to makesure, I have also copied all of my imports over to the working file - which still works. Strange! I have uploaded the file which does work - the only difference I can think of is that the lightbox is being called from within a modal window.
http://djrb.co.uk/lightbox/working_example.html

Comment: @Karthi.L Update: I have identified the positioning of the jQuery include to be causing the problem. In the working example, the include of jQuery isn't required, however if included after the lightbox includes - the light box wont work.

The tester file does require the import of jQuery, but if it appears before the lightbox code, it wont run properly. I have updated both examples - any help greatly appreciated! Rich

Comment: it could be possible of conflict of prototype  and jQuery. Try this this. [link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Comment: @Karthi.L That was spot on, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it could be possible of conflict of prototype and jQuery. 
Try this this. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/ – Karthi.L Apr 22

This was absolutely correct. Change $ for jQuery and on my way.